# Array of files preview onclick

Tags: javascript, preview

Files is an Array used here and passed three items in it. After next `button` i'm getting only first item from `array`. How to get next items one by one `onclick` next `button`?

Please find js code below:

```
function plusSlides(n) {

  var i;
  var currentIndex= 0;

  var files = ["","",""];
   if(currentIndex<files.length)
{
    var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
omyFrame.style.display="block";
omyFrame.src = files[currentIndex];
currentIndex++;
   }   
n++;
}
```

Comment: I think your code snippet does not provide enough context. Where is the next button? Does clicking the next button call `plusSlides`?

Comment: Change `if` to `while`. Also, variables `i` and `n` are useless

Comment: Changing the `if` to `while` will set the iframe source three times on every call and the iframe will always have the ssrc of the last entry in files.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are only getting the first item of the array every time is because you are declaring `currentIndex` and `files` inside the `plusSlides` function. Every time it gets called, `currentIndex` gets reset to `0`.

Try putting these declarations outside the `plusSlides` function:

```
var files = ['', '', ''];
var currentIndex = 0;

function plusSlides() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call your function, you are resetting you `currentIndex` variable since it is in the scope of your function. You can either make your `currentIndex` variable global or keep the information of the current index in your function:

```js
function plusSlides(n) {
    this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex || 0;

    var files = ["", "", ""];
    if(this.currentIndex < files.length)
    {
        // Reset your iframe source here
        this.currentIndex++;
    }
    console.log(this.currentIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value 'n' you are passing to function is not used anywhere inside the function. Also the variables i and currentIndex are getting reset, so in a way they are not useful here. You can update value of currentIndex depending on the parameter passed and then code accordingly.
Try below code,

```
var currentIndex= 0;
var files = ["","",""];

function plusSlides(n) {
       if(n == 1)
          currentIndex++;
       else
          currentIndex--;
      currentIndex = (currentIndex <= -1)? 0 : currentIndex;          
      if(currentIndex<files.length)
      {
          var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
          omyFrame.style.display="block";
          omyFrame.src = files[currentIndex];
      }   
    }
```